# Add row to MS Access database through Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerpivot, vba

I have created a MS Access Database.
I've imported my tables in Excel using Powerpivot.

What I want to do is being able to add a row in Excel. This row then needs to be also added in my MS Access Database because this row should also be added to my powerpivot report.

With which tools should I do this and how?

Answer (score 0):

Create in MS Access a linked data source which links to the Excel file you would like to import. This process is the same as importing a table. But at the end, instead of importing the Excel file in a table or appending the data to an existing MS Access table, just `link the data source by creating a linked table`.

Afterwards, any changes to the Excel file will automatically show in MS Access after a link refresh.